# Neural networks XOR returns incorrect output

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, neural-network

I am wondering why my neural network doesn't work.
I would like to say that I asked simular question to this, but I still have things I don't understand...

Code:

```
import numpy as np
inputs = np.array([
    [[0],[0]],
    [[1],[0]],
    [[0],[1]],
    [[1],[1]]
])

expected_output = np.array([
    [0],
    [1],
    [1],
    [0]
])

epochs = 100
lr = 0.2

hidden_weights = np.array([
    [0.2, 0.3],
    [0.4, 0.5]
])
hidden_bias = np.array([[0.3], [0.6]])

output_weights = np.array([[0.6, 0.7]])
output_bias = np.array([[0.5]])

def sigmoid(z):
    return 1/(1+np.exp(-z))

def sigmoid_derivative(z):
    return z * (1.0-z)

for _ in range(epochs):
    for index, input in enumerate(inputs):
        hidden_layer_activation = np.dot(hidden_weights, input)
        hidden_layer_activation += hidden_bias
        hidden_layer_output = sigmoid(hidden_layer_activation)

        output_layer_activation = np.dot(output_weights, hidden_layer_output)
        output_layer_activation += output_bias
        predicted_output = sigmoid(output_layer_activation)

        #Backpropagation
        output_errors = expected_output[index] - predicted_output
        hidden_errors = output_weights.T.dot(output_errors)
        d_predicted_output = output_errors * sigmoid_derivative(predicted_output)
        d_hidden_layer = hidden_errors * sigmoid_derivative(hidden_layer_output)

        output_weights += np.dot(d_predicted_output, hidden_layer_output.T) * lr
        hidden_weights += np.dot(d_hidden_layer, input.T) * lr

        output_bias += np.sum(d_predicted_output) * lr
        hidden_bias += np.sum(d_hidden_layer) * lr

# NOW THE TESTING,I pass 2 input neurons. One with value 1 and value 1
test = np.array([
    [[1], [1]]
])

hidden_layer_activation = np.dot(hidden_weights, test[0])
hidden_layer_activation += hidden_bias
hidden_layer_output = sigmoid(hidden_layer_activation)

output_layer_activation = np.dot(output_weights, hidden_layer_output)
output_layer_activation += output_bias
predicted_output = sigmoid(output_layer_activation)

print(predicted_output)
```

```
Result : [[0.5]] for inputs 1 and 1

Wanted : [[0]] for inputs 1 and 1
```

I have tested feed-forward-propagation and it works fine.
Errors seems to be good.

I thought updating weights was the problem, but updating weights has the correct formula. This code is from the book "Make your own neural network and it's pretty much same thing I use:

```
self.who += self.lr * numpy.dot((output_errors * final_outputs * (1.0 ­ final_outputs)), numpy.transpose(hidden_outputs))
```

Currently I only forward 1 input of 2 neurons at the time and calculate the errror. I would like it to stay that way very much, instead of forwarding entire test data over and over again.

Is there any way I can do that? 
Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Can you show the trained weights ?

Comment: output_weights. = [[0.21595628 0.23063487]]
hidden_weights = [
[-0.03163078  0.08377066]
 [ 0.22549171  0.32939786]]
Structure is correct atleast

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a small implementation error :

in the Backpropagation, you evaluate :

```
hidden_errors = output_weights.T.dot(output_errors)
```

but your hidden error must be evaluate based on the d_predicted_output, like so :

```
hidden_errors = output_weights.T.dot(d_predicted_output)
```

Also, you should decrease your learning rate and increase to number of epochs. 10000 epochs and lr = 0.1 works for me, but you can fine tune this.

Comment: JESUS I AM STUPIDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD
IT WORKS THANK YOU MANNNNN SO MUCCHHHHHHHH
The problem was the chain rule.... 
I tested it with learning rate of 1 and it still works. I don't know why exactly does it take 10000 epochs..maybe because I rely on 1 input at the time

Comment: yes, you could add batches to decrease the number of epochs. You can plot the loss at each epoch to see how many epochs you really need, 10k is probably way too much